# Replace "/" with "\/"

Tags: sed

I have a string `/tmp/testing` which I want to replace with `\/tmp\/testing`

`sed` works fine as follows:

```
echo testdir=/tmp/testing | sed 's/\//\\\//g'
testdir=\/tmp\/testing
```

However if I try and put this into a variable which I want to use later I get this error:

```
myvar=`echo testdir=/tmp/testing | sed 's/\//\\\//g'`
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: I like to use a different pattern delimiter when my pattern includes `/`.  e.g. `sed 'sX/X\\/Xg'`.  The answer to your question is that backslash inside backticks is a special case of some sort.  Just one more reason never to use backticks.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: on a side note when substituing a fixedd string with / (slash), you may whish to use another separator, e.g. `echo testdir=/tmp/testing | sed 's=/=\\/=g'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$ echo testdir=/tmp/testing | sed 's/\//\\\//g'
testdir=\/tmp\/testing
```

In variable

```
var=$(echo testdir=/tmp/testing | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
```

Comment: Few seconds faster than me!

Comment: It is worth noting that you needn't use `/` in sed in contexts where it is confusing, you can replace it with any other character. So this will work the same: `'s#/#\\/#g'`

Answer (score 11):

The backticks `` `...` `` add a level of indirection that requires another set of `\` escapes. If you use `$( ... )` instead it works correctly and as expected:

```
myvar=$(echo testdir=/tmp/testing | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
echo "$myvar"
testdir=\/tmp\/testing
```

If you insist on using backticks this will work:

```
myvar=`echo testdir=/tmp/testing | sed 's/\//\\\\\//g'`
echo "$myvar"
testdir=\/tmp\/testing
```

Answer (score 4):

Backslash inside backticks is a special case of some sort.  Just one more reason never to use backticks instead of `$(cmd)`.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

You can make the quoting a *lot* more readable by using a different pattern delimiter when your pattern includes `/`.  e.g.

```
myvar=$(printf '%s' "$oldpath" | sed 'sX/X\\/Xg')
```

Or if you know you're using bash, then instead of using `printf` to avoid `echo` munging your data (e.g. if the filename starts with `-`), just use pure bash string manipulation.

```
myvar=${foo//\//\\/}   # sed 'sX/X\\/Xg'
```

This is even more unreadable, because there's no alternative to `/` as a delimiter.  Even better, `/` at the start of a pattern means to replace all occurrences.  Also, the pattern and the replacement are treated differently.  There's no trailing `/` like sed uses, so you don't need to escape `/`es in the the replacement string.  Anyway, different in a lot of ways from sed, which means you should probably leave a comment.

It is "better" in performance and robustness, but not readability or portability, though.  That's about par for the course with shell programming.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bash` variable expansion|replacement

```
testdir="${testdir//\//\\\/}"
```